# Место положение ssis package на SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, integration-services

Когда создается JOB, который использует ssis package, то можно выбрать место положение выполняемого пакета.

С Файловой системой все ясно: Указывай прямой путь к пакету и все.

Есть 2 типа, которые мне непонятны: SQL Server и SSIS Package Store

SQL Server-в примерах указаны относительные пути к пакету. Получается, что я должен класть пакет куда-то в SQL узел?

SSIS Package Store -сказано, что можно грузить пакеты через SQL Managment Studio, но моя 2017 студия не отображает никакие инструменты при работе с пакетами, при коннекте на

Answer (score 2):

С 2017й студией не работал, поэтому напишу как грузятся пакеты на сервер в 2014й. Для других версий все должно быть аналогично, вряд ли будут сильно менять интерфейс.

Сначала нужно создать каталог служб IS, если он еще не был создан:

[image]

Далее, в каталоге SSISDB нужно создать папку (в корень каталога импортировать пакет невозможно!):

[image]

В созданной папке будут под-папки "Проекты" и "Среды", пакеты импортируются в первую:

[image]

В качестве источника пакетов следует указать вариант "файловая система". В дальнейшем импортированный пакет попадет в каталог служб и будет доступен из него.

Comment: Хм... А если у меня нету этого каталога? И еще вопрос: Т.е параметр SQL Server и Store одинаково заполняются пакетом?

Comment: @iluxa1810 про хранилище SQL Server я ничего не знаю

Comment: @iluxa1810 что вы имеете в виду говоря "нет каталога"?

Comment: Отсутствует каталог службы Integration Services. Может что-то дополнительно поставить надо?

Comment: @iluxa1810 а SSDT у вас стоит?

Comment: Вот это? https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt Вроде, поставил, но не появилось.